# XPath not picking up dd tag

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am building a app to pull news item from a website however can't get it to find nodes with the dd tag

Any ideas on where I am going wrong?

HTML

```
<h1>INFO: New Prices</h1>
<dl class='table'>
    <dt>Department:</dt><dd>Sales</dd>
    <dt>Start Date:</dt><dd>28/06/2012</dd>
    <dt>End Date:</dt><dd>20/07/2012</dd>
    <dt>Approved Date:</dt><dd>Jun 28 2012  3:11PM</dd>
</dl>
```

C# Code

```
public void CollectNewsItem(UInt64 aSID)
{
    String URL = WebReader.storyLink + "?SID=" + aSID;

    HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlDocument document = hw.Load(URL);

    HtmlNode n = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//h1");

    Console.WriteLine("Title: " + n.InnerText);

    HtmlNodeCollection nodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//dd");

    foreach (HtmlNode node in nodes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
    }

}
```

Comment: Is it finding the `h1` tags OK?

Comment: yes the h1 tag is being found and outputted correctly

Comment: And I assume that if you changed "//dd" to "//dl" it would find that. How about "//dt"? Maybe its because the `dd`s are inside the `dl'...

Comment: can you show the full html markup?

Comment: too big to post however the rest has no relevance to what I need (they are the only dt/dd tag on the whole page)

Comment: actually xpath are built related to an axis. your code must not be starting with the right node. thats why i was asking for full markup. otherwise your xpath syntax is correct

Comment: doesn't pick up the dl either

Comment: Are you POSITIVE that the markup exists in what you are receiving from the server, and is not created client-side after the page is loaded from javascript? See similar q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11017750/issue-with-htmlagilitypack-parsing-html-using-c-sharp/11018213#comment14406117_11018213

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way as per this thread:

[How to parse these tags?](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/discussions/251811)

To make sure it's working, do this:

```
var node = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//[dt='Department:']");
```

It should pick up the first `dt` at least. If not, there must be a problem in your HTML markup somewhere and the parser is getting confused! :)

Another thing to try... copy/paste the HTML into a simple HTML file and feed your code.

Replace this line ( table between single quotes ):

```
<dl class='table'>
```

with this one ( table between double quotes ):

```
<dl class="table">
```

If the above still doesn't work, try removing the colon ( : ) before closing each `<\dt>` tag. Do this to get to what's causing the problem.

Comment: why did you use predicate? he just want nodes with dd tag

Comment: still can't find it. I have no control over the HTML markup :(

Comment: tried test and it wasn't that however when using a local copy of the page it parses fine. the issue comes when trying to parse a copy on the site

Comment: uhmmmm I see... so the HTML that's being output has some spurious code.

Comment: Not a clue I saved the page locally and ran my app against it and it worked fine. Then ran same code against the same page on the web and it fails to find the tags. strange cause the h1 is working anyway I try it

Comment: In such a case, it'd be good if you compared the HTML from the server with your local copy using a diff compare tool. It'll show you exactly where the difference resides.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to drop to LINQ when using the HtmlAgilityPack. In this case, your select would look like this:

```
IEnumerable<HtmlNode> nodes = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("dd");
```