# How to get hidden InnerHtml of web page that set by javascript?

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, innerhtml

I know that I can get source of web page with this code:

```
browser.DocumentText;
```

some data of page filled by javascript `innetHtml` function and will not visible in `browser.Text` but in `browser`'s output is visible.

How can I get source code of data that added by javascript to page?

Comment: What data type is `browser`?

Comment: @gunr2171 It is `Forms.WebBrowser`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know what type of tag contains the inner HTML you want to get at, you could do something like this (this example loops through the div tags, but you could do p, or table cells, or whatever):

```
HtmlElementCollection collection = browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div");

foreach (HtmlElement element in collection) {
    string html = element.InnerHtml;
    string text = element.InnerText;
    // do something with the HTML or text here...
}
```

Or if you know the specific ID of the element you want to get, use:

```
HtmlElement element = browser.Document.GetElementById("someId123");
if(null != element) // do something with it...
```

Answer (score 1):

You could give [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/releases/view/90925) a try and follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11017750/issue-with-htmlagilitypack-parsing-html-using-c-sharp) answer.

```
HtmlWeb webGet = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = webGet.Load(url);
```