# Button not reachable using the id from "Inspect Element"

Tags: javascript, c#, html, webbrowser-control

I am trying to click on a button which is in a page where I am able to see its id when I select the **Inspect** option on the Chrome browser. The id of the button is `troop_confirm_go` as you can see from below.

```
<input id="troop_confirm_go" style="margin-bottom: 5px" class="troop_confirm_go btn btn-attack" name="submit" type="submit" onload="this.disabled=false;" value="Send Attack">
```

However, when I choose **View page source** on the same page, I am not able to see that button id in the text. Therefore, I assume this is the reason I am not able to reach the button from my code in order to click on it.

Here is my C# code, using .Net Framework 4.5:

```
WebBrowser _wb;

private void PageLoaded(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if(!IamSureThisIsTheCorrectPage())
        return;

    var attack = _wb.Document.GetElementById("troop_confirm_go"); // attack is null
    attack.InvokeMember("click"); // null reference error
}
```

If I can see the button id by inspecting it, I shall be able to click on it right ? How can I achieve this ?

**Edit:** Here is the parent object of the button when I click on `Inspect`. This might be containing information of why I cant access to the button.

```
<form id="command-data-form" action="/game.php?village=39143&amp;screen=place&amp;action=command&amp;h=3447af68" method="post" onsubmit="this.submit.disabled=true;">
.
.
.
<input id="troop_confirm_go" style="margin-bottom: 5px" class="troop_confirm_go btn btn-attack" name="submit" type="submit" onload="this.disabled=false;" value="Saldırı gönder">
<a href="#" id="troop_confirm_train" class="btn btn-img" style="display: none; line-height: 21px">
    <img src="https://dstr.innogamescdn.com/8.44.1/28525/graphic/unit/tiny/snob.png" title="" alt="" class=""> Misyoner saldırısı ekle
</a>
</form>
```

Comment: Is it dynamically added?

Comment: @guradio I am not sure, but probably you are right. In this case, is there anything that I can try ?

Comment: If it's not in page source then it is added with script. Use event delegation

Comment: @charlietfl what do you mean `event delegation` can you please provide further information ?

Comment: it meas it is added dynamically so use `event deledation` check this link http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @guradio you mean I shall use javascript inside my c# program ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `WebBrowser` object has no problem loading the correct DOM. Its totally my fault. I was not able to load the correct URL.

Thanks for your helps [monstertjie_za](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6024969/monstertjie-za)

Answer (score 1):

One problem I have had before as well, and from your code example, it is not clear, but if your button is sitting within a panel in the form, or within another control, it might be useful to use the FindControl() on your parent container that the button sits in.  [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw(v=vs.110).aspx) is the MSDN page for FindControl().

Another option, might be to add JQuery code for the click event of the button.

This JQuery approach should work with either dynamically added DOM elements or static DOM elements, so how ever you have added that button to the page, this function should pick it up:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '#troop_confirm_go', function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Controller/MethodName/',
            data: null,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (ifAnyReturnedData) {
                //Your success logic here
        }
    });
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. I looked into the provided MSDN link and it sounds like you might be right. I'll try to implement it to my code and let you know if it'll work.

Comment: @0014 Cool. Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: I checked the `Findconrtol` property, however it seems like it's used in asp.net applications. Mine is a simple windows application where i am using the `WebBrowser` object. I tried making them work together but I failed. Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: You can maybe give the InnerHtml a try, here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17094136/how-to-get-hidden-innerhtml-of-web-page-that-set-by-javascript
Show the exact layout of your content, and I will try and help you, for example, the control that your button resides in, I would like to see that

Comment: Thanks for your offer, but for me to provide you the page source you need an account which has certain kind of progress. Even if I share it through a text file it would be difficult for to find the button inside it. It is a very long file :)

Comment: No I`m still dealing with this problem. But I found out that, I am able to see the id on page source using other browsers. So I asked another question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35877787/webbrowser-id-access-not-in-documenttext-but-in-page-source