# WebBrowser ID Access - not in DocumentText but in Page Source

Tags: c#, html, dom, com, webbrowser-control

I am using the `WebBrowser` object, for web automation purposes on a windows form .Net Framework 4.5 application. In a certain page, I am not able to see the id in my `WebBrowser.DocumentText` even though I can see it when I open **View page source** from an actual browser.

This is the code that I always use to get the `HtmlElement` inside a page.

```
var attack = wb.Document.GetElementById("target_attack");
```

To sum up how can I retrieve an ID that is not inside DocumentText but inside the page source ?

**Edit:** This is how it looks like in the **Page Source** data. Just press **conrol + f** and search for the id named `troop_confirm_go`:

```
<table align="center" id="contentContainer" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table class="content-border" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td id="inner-border">
                            <table class="main" align="left">
                                <tr>
                                    <td id="content_value">


                                        <form id="command-data-form" action="/game.php?village=39143&amp;screen=place&amp;action=command&amp;h=c86dc3bd" method="post" onsubmit="this.submit.disabled=true;">
<input type="hidden" name="attack" value="true" />

<h2>Barbar köyü hedefindeki saldırıyı onayla</h2>


<input type="hidden" name="ch" value="b5aa6baff4c83d16a08edb7709204aefd3e85650" />
<input type="hidden" name="x" value="489" />
<input type="hidden" name="y" value="690" />
<input type="hidden" name="source_village" value="39143">
<input type="hidden" name="action_id" value="1880595" />

<table class="vis" width="300">
    <tr>
        <th  colspan="2">
                            Komut
                        </th>
                </tr>
    <tr><td>Hedef:</td><td><span class="village_anchor" data-player="0" data-id="42165"><a href="/game.php?village=39143&amp;screen=info_village&amp;id=42165" >Barbar köyü (489|690) K64</a></span></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Süre:</td><td>0:40:15</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Varış:</td>
        <td id="date_arrival">
            <span class="relative_time" data-duration="2415">
            bugün saat 23:46 
            </span>
                        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>Moral:</td><td><b>100%</b></td></tr>                <tr><td colspan="2"><span class="icon header ressources" title="Taşıma kapasitesi"></span>250</td></tr>    </table><br />

<table class="vis" id="place_confirm_units">
    <tr>
        <th class="train-ui" style="display: none"></th>
        <th width="50"><a href="#" class="unit_link" data-unit="spear"><img src="https://dstr.innogamescdn.com/8.44.1/28599/graphic/unit/unit_spear.png" title="Mızrakçı" alt="" class="" /></a></th><th width="50"><a href="#" class="unit_link" data-unit="sword"><img src="https://dstr.innogamescdn.com/8.44.1/28599/graphic/unit/unit_sword.png" title="Kılıç Ustası" alt="" class="faded" /></a></th><th width="50"><a href="#" class="unit_link" data-unit="axe"><img src="https://dstr.innogamescdn.com/8.44.1/28599/graphic/unit/unit_axe.png" title="Baltacı" alt="" class="faded" /></a></th><th width="50"><a href="#" class="unit_link" data-unit="spy"><img src="https://dstr.innogamescdn.com/8.44.1/28599/graphic/unit/unit_spy.png" title="Casus" alt="" class="faded" /></a></th><th width="50"><a href="#" class="unit_link" data-unit="light"><img src="https://dstr.innogamescdn.com/8.44.1/28599/graphic/unit/unit_light.png" title="Hafif atlı" alt="" class="faded" /></a></th><th width="50"><a href="#" class="unit_link" data-unit="heavy"><img src="https://dstr.innogamescdn.com/8.44.1/28599/graphic/unit/unit_heavy.png" title="Ağır atlı" alt="" class="faded" /></a></th><th width="50"><a href="#" class="unit_link" data-unit="ram"><img src="https://dstr.innogamescdn.com/8.44.1/28599/graphic/unit/unit_ram.png" title="Şahmerdan" alt="" class="faded" /></a></th><th width="50"><a href="#" class="unit_link" data-unit="catapult"><img src="https://dstr.innogamescdn.com/8.44.1/28599/graphic/unit/unit_catapult.png" title="Mancınık" alt="" class="faded" /></a></th><th width="50"><a href="#" class="unit_link" data-unit="knight"><img src="https://dstr.innogamescdn.com/8.44.1/28599/graphic/unit/unit_knight.png" title="Şövalye" alt="" class="faded" /></a></th><th width="50"><a href="#" class="unit_link" data-unit="snob"><img src="https://dstr.innogamescdn.com/8.44.1/28599/graphic/unit/unit_snob.png" title="Misyoner" alt="" class="faded" /></a></th>
                </tr>
    <tr class="train-ui" style="display: none">
        <th>Köy birimleri</th>
        <td class='unit-item unit-item-spear '>10</td><td class='unit-item unit-item-sword '>10</td><td class='unit-item unit-item-axe hidden'>0</td><td class='unit-item unit-item-spy hidden'>0</td><td class='unit-item unit-item-light hidden'>0</td><td class='unit-item unit-item-heavy hidden'>0</td><td class='unit-item unit-item-ram hidden'>0</td><td class='unit-item unit-item-catapult hidden'>0</td><td class='unit-item unit-item-knight hidden'>0</td><td class='unit-item unit-item-snob hidden'>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="units-row">
        <th class="train-ui train-name" style="display: none"><span>Saldırı #1</span></th>
        <td class='unit-item unit-item-spear '>10</td><td class='unit-item unit-item-sword hidden'>0</td><td class='unit-item unit-item-axe hidden'>0</td><td class='unit-item unit-item-spy hidden'>0</td><td class='unit-item unit-item-light hidden'>0</td><td class='unit-item unit-item-heavy hidden'>0</td><td class='unit-item unit-item-ram hidden'>0</td><td class='unit-item unit-item-catapult hidden'>0</td><td class='unit-item unit-item-knight hidden'>0</td><td class='unit-item unit-item-snob hidden'>0</td>
                </tr>
    <tr class="train-ui units-sum" style="display: none">
        <th>Toplam</th>
        <td class='unit-item unit-item-spear '>10</td><td class='unit-item unit-item-sword hidden'>0</td><td class='unit-item unit-item-axe hidden'>0</td><td class='unit-item unit-item-spy hidden'>0</td><td class='unit-item unit-item-light hidden'>0</td><td class='unit-item unit-item-heavy hidden'>0</td><td class='unit-item unit-item-ram hidden'>0</td><td class='unit-item unit-item-catapult hidden'>0</td><td class='unit-item unit-item-knight hidden'>0</td><td class='unit-item unit-item-snob hidden'>0</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<br />

    <input type="hidden" name="spear" value="10" />
    <input type="hidden" name="sword" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="axe" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="spy" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="light" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="heavy" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ram" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="catapult" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="knight" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="snob" value="0" />

<h3 class="error" id="train_noble_warning" style="display: none">
    Misyonerler koruma olmadan gönderilmemeli!
</h3>

<input id="troop_confirm_go" style="margin-bottom: 5px" class="troop_confirm_go btn btn-attack" name="submit" type="submit" onload="this.disabled=false;" value="Saldırı gönder" />
<a href="#" id="troop_confirm_train" class="btn btn-img" style="display: none; line-height: 21px">
    <img src="https://dstr.innogamescdn.com/8.44.1/28599/graphic/unit/tiny/snob.png" title="" alt="" class="" /> Misyoner saldırısı ekle
</a>
</form>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#troop_confirm_go').focus();
            Place.confirmScreen.init({"type":"attack","units":["spear","sword","axe","spy","light","heavy","ram","catapult","knight","snob"],"send_units":{"spear":10,"sword":0,"axe":0,"spy":0,"light":0,"heavy":0,"ram":0,"catapult":0,"knight":0,"snob":0},"available_units":{"spear":10,"sword":10,"axe":0,"spy":0,"light":0,"heavy":0,"ram":0,"catapult":0,"knight":0,"snob":0}});
        });
</script>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <p class="server_info">
        Sunucu saati: <span id="serverTime">23:05:56</span> <span id="serverDate">08/03/2016</span>
        <span id="dev_console" style="display: none"><b>|</b> <a href="?screen=74:72:69:62:61:6c:77:61:72:73">developer console</a></span>
                </p>

</td>
<td class="bg_right" id="SkyScraperAdCell">
    <div class="bg_right"> </div>
                <div id="SkyScraperAd">
            <script type='text/javascript'><!--//<![CDATA[
var m3_u = (location.protocol=='https:'?'https://openx.innogames.de/delivery/ajs.php':'http://openx.innogames.de/delivery/ajs.php');
var m3_r = Math.floor(Math.random()*99999999999);
if (!document.MAX_used) document.MAX_used = ',';
document.write ("<scr"+"ipt type='text/javascript' src='"+m3_u);
document.write ("?zoneid=1620");
document.write ('&amp;cb=' + m3_r);
if (document.MAX_used != ',') document.write ("&amp;exclude=" + document.MAX_used);
document.write (document.charset ? '&amp;charset='+document.charset : (document.characterSet ? '&amp;charset='+document.characterSet : ''));
document.write ("&amp;loc=" + escape(window.location));
if (document.referrer) document.write ("&amp;referer=" + escape(document.referrer));
if (document.context) document.write ("&context=" + escape(document.context));
if (document.mmm_fo) document.write ("&amp;mmm_fo=1");
document.write ("'><\/scr"+"ipt>");
//]]>--></script><noscript><a href='http://openx.innogames.de/delivery/ck.php?n=a47300e4&amp;cb=INSERT_RANDOM_NUMBER_HERE' target='_blank'><img src='http://openx.innogames.de/delivery/avw.php?zoneid=1620&amp;cb=INSERT_RANDOM_NUMBER_HERE&amp;n=a47300e4' border='0' alt='' /></a></noscript>

        </div>
        </td>
</tr>

                    <tr>
            <td class="bg_leftborder"> </td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="bg_rightborder"> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="newStyleOnly">
            <td class="bg_bottomleft">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="bg_bottomcenter">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="bg_bottomright">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
                    </table><!-- .main_layout -->


<script type="text/javascript">

var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-1897727-23']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
_gaq.push(['_gat._anonymizeIp']);


(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
 ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
 (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(ga);
})();

</script>


            <div id="world_selection_clicktrap" class="evt-world-selection-toggle">
    </div>
    <div id="world_selection_popup">
        <div class="servers-list-top"></div>
        <div id="servers-list-block">

        </div>
        <div class="servers-list-bottom"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="chat-open-buffer"></div>

    <div id="bottom">
        <div id="chat-wrapper">
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            <a href="#" id="unsupported-browser">
                <img src="https://dstr.innogamescdn.com/8.44.1/28599/graphic/error.png" title="" alt="" class="" /> Desteklenmeyen tarayıcı
            </a>
            <div id="linkContainer">
                                    <a href="#" class="world_button_active evt-world-selection-toggle">32. Dünya</a>
                                    <a href="http://forum.klanlar.org/index.php" class="footer-link" target="_blank">Forum</a>
                &nbsp;-&nbsp;
                <a href="http://help.klanlar.org/wiki/Ana_sayfa" class="footer-link" target="_blank">Yardım</a>
                                        &nbsp;-&nbsp;
                    <a href="http://blog.klanlar.org" class="footer-link" target="_blank">Blog</a>
                                                        &nbsp;-&nbsp;
                <a href="/game.php?village=39143&amp;screen=settings&amp;mode=ticket" class="footer-link" target="_blank">Destek</a>
                                                            &nbsp;-&nbsp;
                    <a href="/game.php?village=39143&amp;screen=settings&amp;mode=ref&amp;source=bottom_menu" class="footer-link">Oyuncu davet et</a>
                                                        &nbsp;-&nbsp;
                <a href="/game.php?village=39143&amp;screen=memo" class="footer-link">Not defteri</a>
                                                                            &nbsp;-&nbsp;
                <a href="/game.php?village=39143&amp;screen=&amp;action=logout&amp;h=c86dc3bd" target="_top" class="footer-link">Çıkış</a>
                                </div>
        </div>
    </div>




<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    Timing.init(1457471156.4343);
    TribalWars.initTab('1458e0d83d');



        WorldSwitch.init();
    WorldSwitch.worldsURL = '/game.php?village=39143&screen=api&ajax=world_switch&';

        HotKeys.init();

        Connection.connect('tr32.klanlar.org', 8082, 'cec5b6e92cde', true);

        UI.Notification.enabled = true;




    });
```

Comment: What does your markup look like? Can you include more in your question?

Comment: @ZachM. added the HTML page source code

Comment: Why not use javascript to write that value to a hidden property that you would then be able to grab

Comment: @ZachM. this is the element that i am trying to get,
`<input id="troop_confirm_go" style="margin-bottom: 5px" class="troop_confirm_go btn btn-attack" name="submit" type="submit" onload="this.disabled=false;" value="Saldırı gönder" />` i cannot see any hidden property attached to it.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you execute your `wb.Document.GetElementById` after some kind of `wb_DocumentCompleted` event.
However, as you can see in your html source, there is javascript being executed on the element you are queuing for, making it busy and inaccessible by that time.

What you might want to try is queuing for an element, which is populated after "troop_confirm_go" (e.g. "troop_confirm_train") and as soon as this element does not return nothing, you can try and get the element you're trying to access again.

**EDIT:** Something like this should do the trick:
This function queues for the item with the id specified in key every 20 ms for 10 seconds. If it is not populated it is cancelled.

```
public async Task WaitForElementToLoad(String key)
    {
        element = wb.Document.GetElementById(key);
        CancellationToken ct = new CancellationTokenSource(10000).Token;

        var doc = wb.Document;
        while (true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(20, ct);

            element = wb.Document.GetElementById(key);
            if (element != null)
                if (element.InnerHtml != null)
                    break;

            doc = wb.Document;
        }
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }
```

Calling it like this should get you your troop_confirm_go:

```
await WaitForElementToLoad("troop_confirm_train");
element = wb.Document.GetElementById("troop_confirm_go");
```

Note that the function you call this from needs to be `async` too.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Yes, your are correct with your assumption. So if I'm not mistaken you mean that I should try something like this inside `DocumentCompleted` event; var confirm = _wb.Document.GetElementById("troop_confirm_train"); if (confirm == null) return; is that correct ?

Comment: You need to keep queuing for it, until the item is populated. Please look at the edit in my answer.

Comment: Hmm I see, since it is asyn it is going to be hard to implement the solution into my own system. At least I will know what causes the problem. I'm currently applying your code to see if it'll work. I'll let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your input. While trying to apply your code I realized a big mistake. Even though the urls were same, my DocumentText was not the DOM that I was looking for. This stupid coincidence made me spent a lot of hours. It's totally my fault. Now WebBrowser is loading the correct DOM as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The `WebBrowser` object has no problem loading the correct DOM. Its totally my fault. I was not able to load the correct URL.